# Adding textbox dynamically in repeater after each element in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have binded data to repeater control from DB. Now I have to add text box dynamically after each element binded in repeater.
E.g.
Item1 TextBox1
Item2 TextBox2
Item3 TextBox3

I have used following code on repeater itembound event to add textbox.

```
 if (dtSubCategories.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        CheckBoxList chklCat = e.Item.FindControl("chklCategory") as CheckBoxList;

                        if (chklCat != null)
                        {
                            chklCat.DataSource = dtSubCategories;
                            TextBox t = new TextBox();
                            t.ID = e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString();
                            e.Item.Controls.Add(t);
                            chklCat.DataBind();  

                        }
                    }
```

But this code is giving output in following format
Item1
Item2
Item3
TextBox1
Please let me know how to implement this.

Comment: why dont u add your textbox in itemtemplate  ?

Comment: I tried it as well but it adds only one text box after binding entire list to repeater. E.g. ListItem1 ListItem2 ListItem3 <textBox1> But I want it like ListItem1 <textbox1> ListItem2 <textbox2> likewise.